# Getting user's location while making a phone call

Tags: ios, core-location

I need to get exact location (as much accurate as possible) in background while making a call to a phone number (The call will be made from app). As far as I understand from documentation, I can listen to significant changes of location in background. I am wondering how accurate is a significant update and when will it trigger.

I need the location where the call is made because it will be an emergency call. And it's not a good idea to listen to location in foreground and then make a call because it will be an emergency situation - call will be made immediately.

Is there a solution to get accurate location of user in background? What do you recommend?

**Edit:** Location will be sent to server immediately.

Comment: "I can listen to significant changes of location in background. " don't most phones have GPRS? :S This is a weird question, but, an interesting one!

Answer (score 0):

As for the accuracy, you can get accurate location in the background, under those [conditions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html):

> Getting Location Events in the Background
>
> If your application needs location updates delivered whether the application is in the foreground or background, there are multiple options for doing so. The preferred option is to use the significant location change service to wake your application at appropriate times to handle new events. However, if your application needs to use the standard location service, you can declare your application as needing background location services.
>
> An application should request background location services only if the absence of those services would impair its ability to operate. In addition, any application that requests background location services should use those services to provide a tangible benefit to the user. For example, a turn-by-turn navigation application would be a likely candidate for background location services because of its need to track the user’s position and report when it is time to make the next turn.

As for getting location during phone call, I didn't use it myself, but navigation apps like '[waze](http://www.waze.com)' do inform turns and navigation events during a phone call so I guess what you ask is possible.

If I understand your needs, you have 2 options:

1. If you think that the user will be static then simply get the user location right before the call is made. Or better when your app is lunched to make the emergency call.
2. If the user is moving then you can 'ask' to get background location events. **Even then** you should consider using 'significant-change location service' as you don't need more then the user location. The standard 'location services' are used for navigation 'Turn by turn' services.

**LAST COMMENT **

If your app is an emergency app you shold read the "Tips for Conserving Battery Power" in the previous link. you don't want your user battery to empty while tracking his location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just need to track location once before or during the call. User will be probably stationary. I don't know if I'm guaranteed to get location in a 3-5 second period. The call should be made as soon as possible because it's more critical to make the call. I won't probably need a power conservation method, I'll shut down location service after first location update.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you like add that flag in your app plist file to request Location Service to be running in the background mode.

Then in your app, when the user presses the "call" button, you can do your normal CLLocationManager didUpdateToLocation, right before you perform the call.

In your didUpdateToLocation method, you can record the user's location either in a TXT file written to the application sandbox Library/Cache folder or you can use NSUserDefaults.

Note: I've written an app that records the user's GPS location as they drive even when the user presses the lock screen, so I am confident your app can write the GPS coordinate to a TXT file even when the app is minimized, as long as you start your location manager.